# Finding all combinations of words that form a word

Tags: string, algorithm, combinations, dynamic-programming

I have a list of words, some words can be formed using two or more other words, I have to return all such combinations.

Input :

```py
words = ["leetcode","leet","code","le","et","etcode","de","decode","deet"]
```

Output:

> ("leet","code") ("le","et","code") ("de","code") etc..

What I tried:

1) Trying all possible combinations takes way too much time and is a bad idea.

2) I sense some form of dynamic programming here, like I can use the solution of **"leet"** in **"leetcode"**. But I am unable to exactly formulate it in psuedocode. How do I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Simple way:
Sort word list.
For every word A (`leetcode`) with binary search find range of words being prefixes of the word A ('le', `leet`).
For every valid prefix repeat searching for the rest of the word (i.e. look for `etcode` and `code`), and so on

Answer (score 1):

Can you use every word just once? For example if you have `de`, and `dede`, is (`de`, `de`) an answer? I just assume each word appears once for simplicity, you have a lot of words but no memory constraints.

1- build a custom tree, such that each node is like below:

```
class node():
   is_there_a_word_that_ends_here = T/F
   children = dict() # other nodes, key is the letter of the node
```

then for example if you have three words like ["ab", "abc", "ade", "c"] then you would have a tree like below (I put a * sign if is_there_a_word_that_ends_here value of node is true)

```
head ---a---b*---c*
    |   |
    |   L-d----e*
    |
    L--c*
```

2- group words with respect to their lengths. start from the word with smallest length, because you would like to know the "breakdowns" of smaller words when you reach to larger words. here you can do this recursively with a function say `add_word_to_result` which could(should) cache results.

```
results = dict() # keys: possible words you can reach, values: ways to reach them
for word in words_in_ascending_length:
   add_word_to_result(word, tree, results)
```

and `add_word_to_result` would start moving through the tree. if it sees `is_there_a_word_that_ends_here` in a node, it calls the `add_word_to_result(remaining_part_of_the_word, tree, results)`. for example if you have "abc", then you would see * in "ab" then call `add_word_to_result("c", tree, results)`.

Implementing the recursive function is the "fun part" of the question (also more time consuming part), so I leave that to you. Also, as a bonus you can think of a way to avoid adding duplicates to results in an efficient way (because duplicates will happen in some cases).

(Edit: and maybe you need to cache breakdowns for existing words and non existing words -breakdown of an ending of a word for example- separately so that you dont have to separate them before you return the result, if this sentence makes any sense)

I hope this helps.

Bonus: sample code (havent really tested it but should work, and there is a significant improvement you can make but Im too lazy to do it now. You can change the structure a bit to pass `results` to `add_word_to_result`, so that you remember all possible combinations up to thus far, so instead of `add_word_to_result(head, head, words_left[1:], combinations, words_passed+words_left[0]+",")`, you just use that and do not do an unnecessary recursion)

```
words = ["leetcode", "leet", "code", "le", "et", "etcode", "de", "decode", "deet"]


class node():
    def __init__(self, letter, is_there_a_word_that_ends_here):
        self.letter = letter # not really used but it feels weird to not have it in class
        self.is_there_a_word_that_ends_here = is_there_a_word_that_ends_here
        self.children = dict()


# actually defining tree is redundant you can just merge tree and node class together, but maybe this is more explicit
class Tree():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = node(None, False)

    def add(self, word, head=None):
        if head is None:
            head=self.head

        if word[0] not in head.children.keys():
            head.children[word[0]] = node(word[0], False)

        if len(word) == 1:
            head.children[word[0]].is_there_a_word_that_ends_here = True
        else:
            self.add(word[1:], head=head.children[word[0]])


words = sorted(words, key=lambda w: len(w))
results = dict()
tree = Tree()
for word in words:
    tree.add(word)


def add_word_to_result(head, current_node, words_left, combinations, words_passed):
    if words_left[0] in current_node.children.keys():
        # this does not have to happen because we call this function with words that are not in the list as well
        next_node = current_node.children[words_left[0]]
        if len(words_left) == 1 and next_node.is_there_a_word_that_ends_here:
            combinations.append(words_passed+words_left)
        elif next_node.is_there_a_word_that_ends_here:
            add_word_to_result(head, head, words_left[1:], combinations, words_passed+words_left[0]+",")
            add_word_to_result(head, next_node, words_left[1:], combinations, words_passed + words_left[0])
        else:
            add_word_to_result(head, next_node, words_left[1:], combinations, words_passed+words_left[0])


for word in words:
    results[word] = []
    add_word_to_result(tree.head, tree.head, word, results[word], "")

print(results)

# {'le': ['le'], 'et': ['et'], 'de': ['de'], 'leet': ['le,et', 'leet'], 'code': ['code'], 'deet': ['de,et', 'deet'], 'etcode': ['et,code', 'etcode'], 'decode': ['de,code', 'decode'], 'leetcode': ['le,et,code', 'le,etcode', 'leet,code', 'leetcode']}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the trie ? Wouldn't a set work better ? It would have lookup O(1) time .

Comment: If we assume hashing is instantaneous, yes. But I assume hashing would use each character in each word. Tree also does the same, so I dont see any significant advantage of using a set here but Im not quite the expert so if there are any objections I’d love to hear. The reason I’d use tree is, you can easily find the words that have the same beginning as your word of interest. In set you dont have any connection between similar words so you need to search, or come up with another index.

Comment: @AjinkyaGawali see the edit :) if you could send me the leetcode link I would like to check if I missed anything

Answer (score 0):

In recursion, it is important to figure out the base case. Since you are asking for all combinations, looks like you need to return a 2D array.

[image]

When I reach "", what should I return? this is the main question that you should be asking yourself when you solve any recursive problem. Since structure will be will be 2D array, I should be returning [[]] when I hit "", and populate it as I go back to "LEETCODE".

[image]

this is the logic that you have to implement. From "Leetcode", I go over all the given words and find that "leet" is one word that exists in the array. One thing you have to be careful, a word that is given in the words array, has to be prefix. for example, if the target word was "eleetcode", we would not use "leet", may be "ele" or "eleet". Based on these info, you just have to implement the coding. I will in python:

```
class Solution:
    def construct(self,target:str,words:list[str]):
        # we stored in result
        result=[]
        # Base case
        if target=='':
            return [[]]
        # our tree will be branched out to len(words)
        for word in words:
            # we look for a word that is prefix to our target word
            
            if target.startswith(word):
                # if we found a word, then we are removing, and testing with the new target word
                suffix=target[len(word):]
                # we are recursively calling till the edge case
                bubble_up_ways=self.construct(suffix,words)
                # in each level I am adding the word as shown in the image
                combinations=[[*way,word] for way in bubble_up_ways]
                if combinations:
                    result.extend(combinations)
        return result
```

However, this is a brute force solution. That means we are going to call recursive calls for each word in the given array. We are going to have len(words)=n branches for sure. And we are going to have recursive calls till the base case.  Now what is the worst case that to reach the base case. Imagine we have our array ["l","e","e","t","c","o","d","e"]. So to reach the base case we will have len("leetcode")=m recursive calls. m is also called height. so we are going to have "n over m" recursive calls. Plus for each recursive call, we are slicing the array `combinations=[[*way,word] for way in bubble_up_ways]` which is also takes "m" time. So over all

```
  T:O(n^m * m) # this is exponential, because exponent is a variable
```

For space complexity, we are having "m" recursive calls on the stack, and also we are storing `result` array which can be "n" length. Because each branch might return a combination so we have to store "n" arrays.

```
  S: O(m*n)
```

In recursive functions, if we store each result before we return, instead of making the same calculations, we will have just retrieve the result from the store. That way for each branch we do not have to have "m" recursion calls till the base case. Here is the memorized version, we are just passing an memo={} store the calculated result

```
def memoized(self,target:str,words:List[str],memo={}):
    if target in memo:
        return memo[target]
    if target=="":
        return [[]]
    result=[]
    for word in words:
        if target.startswith(word):
            suffix=target[len(word):]
            buble_up_ways=self.memoized(suffix,words,memo)
            combinations=[[*way,word] for way in buble_up_ways]
            if combinations:
                result.extend(combinations)
    # memorize before returning value
    memo[target] = result
    return result
```

However, unlike any other dynamic problems, this will not change the time complexity. Because we store the values if we know that there will duplicates but here after we trim the "leetcode" with one of the words in the array, we are going to get different result. For example

```
leetcode - leet ---> code # first branch
   leetcode - le   ---> etcode # second branch
```